# Python: Inheritance of class data variable

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have some class...

```
class Person:
    name = ""
    phone = 0
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name;
        self.phone = phone;

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, subjects):
        self.subjects;


person = Person("Daniel", "0");
student = Student("Chemistry")
```

I want to inherit data of person variable to the student variable... How to?

Comment: Have you tried making `Student` a subclass yet? What happened when you did?

Comment: So, what happened when you tried this, and what did you expect to happen instead? If you have a traceback for an exception, include it.

Comment: And generally, you need to call the parent implementation if you override a method but still need the original to run. Here you have `Person.__init__` and `Student.__init__`. The latter runs, not the former. How will you also pass the name and phone number to the student?

Comment: You may want to carefully read this tutorial: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php. It covers your case just about exactly.

Comment: Also, you've made `name` and `phone` class-level variables, which you shadow in every instance. Likely, you don't mean to do that. You should probably just delete those first two lines in your `Person` class.